# How to get the preceding element?

Tags: xpath

```
<p class="small" style="margin: 16px 4px 8px;">
<b>
<a class="menu-root" href="#pg-jump">Pages</a>
 :  
<b>1</b>
, 
<a class="pg" href="viewforum.php?f=941&start=50">2</a>
, 
<a class="pg" href="viewforum.php?f=941&start=100">3</a>
 ... 
<a class="pg" href="viewforum.php?f=941&start=8400">169</a>
, 
<a class="pg" href="viewforum.php?f=941&start=8450">170</a>
, 
<a class="pg" href="viewforum.php?f=941&start=8500">171</a>
<a class="pg" href="viewforum.php?f=941&start=50">Next.</a>
</b>
</p>
```

I want to catch `a` element containing 171. So basically the preceding element from the Next.

```
//a[.='Next.']//Not sure how to use preceding here
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use this `xpath`:

```
//a[.="Next."]/preceding::a[1]
```

---

If I were to diagram it out, using an `X` to represent the current location, it would look like this:

```
------------------+------+------------------
preceding-sibling | self | following-sibling
------------------|------|------------------
last() ...  2   1 |  X   | 1   2  ... last()
------------------+------+------------------
```

Comment: This diagram is so useful! I have been confused by the indexing rules for so  long!

Answer (score 5):

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Next.')]/preceding::a[contains(text(), '171')]
```

**Explanation of xpath:** Using `text` method along with `<a>` tag and then move ahead with `preceding` keyword to locate the element `171`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and if you didn't know the containing element preceding the "Name." element this wouldn't be a solution for you.  BUT, if you were wanting to find exactly that element and there are several "171" elements all over the page. 
 The way to distinguish it from the rest, you could use the following.

```
//p[b[contains(., 'Next.')]]//a[contains(., '171')]
```